# Why my lav mic makes static when connected to PC, but not if connected to mixer?

Tags: microphone, noise, lavalier

I just bought a lav mics for an accordion and when I connect it to the PC using minijack to USB adapter and transimitter/receiver and moving a wire, I hear static crackling. From that I understand that a mic cable is probably broken. But if I connect it to the mixer with minijack to jack adapter, I don't hear that static noise when moving a cable, I can only hear a feedback from the mixer when I touch a cable, but I don't hear that feedback on PC when I touch a cable, but absolutely no static noise. Why I don't hear static noise on mixer.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could point us to the exact model of lav you are using.

Comment: …& the PC… & mixer… & what the pinouts for them all are. This still doesn't fall under "sound design", it's a hardware connectivity issue best asked of the hardware manufacturers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any additional information, this sounds like a balanced v unbalanced issue.

In very simple terms, a balanced connection uses 3 contacts in a way that helps to cancel out cable noise or other external interference.

Your mic is probably capable of delivering a balanced signal that your mixer is capable of using but that your USB adaptor is not. Your USB adaptor is not able to take advantage of the noise cancellation so delivers all the noise directly into your PC along with the signal.

You should be able to verify this simply by checking the minijack connection on your mic: If it has three connectors (tip, ring and sleeve) then it's most likely delivering a balanced signal. If, on the other hand, it only has two connectors (tip and sleeve) then you can ignore everything else I've written here! :)

Comment: We don't know what lav it is. There are a myriad ultra-cheap [5 buck] lavs these days with TRRS for a laptop, with only mic & ground connected.  Headset mini condenser without the headset. OMTP/CTIA is anyone's guess.  There are also DSLR versions, TRS. They use the tiny DC voltage in a laptop's jack socket, or a battery in the lav. It is, of course, not obvious the other two terminals are not connected to anything, which is why you need either good guesswork or a pinout for all components. We have not enough information in the question to even begin to make suggestions.

Comment: @7HzResearch Thanks for the explanation, yes mic minijack is TRS. It's Kimafun wireless accordion mic. Does it mean that my cable is bad if I hear a noise when it's connected via minijack to USB adapter? Additionally, I noticed that on Focusrite 2i2 audio interface I hear some noise when moving a cable but very little. On the mixer I don't hear any noise at all. The music signal is never cut off by moving a cable. When using mixer, I plug transmitter into mono jack. When using audio interface I plug it into to jack on jack/XLR combo.

Comment: @7HzResearch Does it mean that my cable is bad if I hear a noise when it's connected via minijack to USB adapter when moving a mic cable?*

Comment: @7HzResearch I just tried again to use minijack to USB adapter and if I turn on a lot of gain I hear some noise, but it doesn't seem like moving the cable influence that noise. Now it's a bit strange that for me that it looked like the noise was caused by moving the cable.